# Modifying .xlsx file works instantly when tested in Eclipse, but when executed as a .jar file, it takes upwards of 20 seconds

Tags: excel, performance, apache, apache-poi, formula

I have the three methods that take the longest and then my run() method; the rest of the code takes a negligible amount of time. I'm just confused as to why it would run instantly in Eclipse but not be able to do the same when I run it from a .jar file.

It is around 120x slower when run from the .jar file. Is it my code or is there something else going on here?

```
public void modifyCell(String input, int rowNum, int column, Workbook wb) throws IOException {

    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(column);
    cell = row.createCell(column);

    CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    cell.setCellValue(input);

    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    cell = row.getCell(column+1);
    evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
    row = sheet.getRow(3);
    cell = row.getCell(getFinalFormula(site));
    evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);

    evaluateTopFormulas(wb);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(workbook);
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();

}

public void evaluateTopFormulas(Workbook wb){

    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
    Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(6);
    evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
    row = sheet.getRow(2);
    cell = row.getCell(6);
    evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
}

public int getRow(Workbook wb, int column){ // i also think this part is very poorly written 
but I don't know how to go about it differently.
 All I want is to get the next blank cell in a column after the 4th cell.

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    int i = 4;
    Row startRow = sheet1.getRow(i);
    Cell cell = startRow.getCell(column);
    Row row;
    try {
        while (!(cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)){
            row = sheet1.getRow(i++);
            cell = row.getCell(column);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
    if (i == 4){
        return i;
    }
    long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println(estimatedTime + " getRow");
    return i-1;


}

public void run(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Adding to Invoice");
        Workbook wb = openWorkbook();
        int column = getColumn(site);
        int row = getRow(wb, column);
        modifyCell(input, row, column, wb);
        System.out.println(input + " was added to " + workbook);
    } catch (InvalidFormatException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the same heap size on both JVMs?

Comment: @Gagravarr I just ran a test and here were the results:----
Eclipse test:
Used Memory:53
Free Memory:178
Total Memory:232
Max Memory:2724
------
.Jar tests
Used Memory:97
Free Memory:114
Total Memory:212
Max Memory:2724
----
Would that be enough to make a difference like I'm seeing?